# Alertify no funciona si no coloco un alert despues

Tags: javascript, alertify

¿Qué tal? Tengo un inconveniente con `Alertify.js`, cuando uso un mensaje de `Alertify` no se visualiza a no ser que use el `alert` típico después de el de `Alertify`.

```
function validar(){
    var usuario,password;
    var encontrado = false;
    usuario = document.getElementById("user").value;
    password =document.getElementById("pass").value;
    for (var i = 0; i <usuarios.length; i++){
        if (usuario== usuarios[i]){
            encontrado=true;
            if (password == pass[i]){
                alertify.alert("hola");
                break;
            }else{
                alert("el usuario y la password no coinciden");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (encontrado==false){
        alert("el usuario no existe");
    }
}
```

Pero no aparece el `Alertify` a menos que coloque el `alert` después del `Alertify.alert();`
¿Cuál puede ser el inconveniente?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login Tamagoshi</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alertify.core.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alertify.default.css">
 
 
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="contenedor-form">
  <div class="toggle">
   <span>Crear Cuenta</span>
  </div>
  <div class="formulario" id="loginform" onsubmit="return validar();">
   <h2>Iniciar Sesion</h2>
   <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required id="user">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required id="pass">
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion" id="loginbtn">

   </form>
  </div>

  <div class="formulario">
   <h2>Crear Cuenta</h2>
   <form action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">

   </form>
   <audio src="music/login.mp3" autoplay="true" loop=true></audio>

  </div>

  <div class="reset-password">
   <a href="#" id="reset" onclick="recuperar()">Olvide mi contraseña?</a> 
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Te aparece algún error en consola?

Comment: me aparece como no difinida pero agrege debidamente las librerias en el index

Comment: y el archivo .js si lo estas incluyendo correctamente ? seria muy útil si puedes poner como importas el archivo y una captura del error. Por que si te sale que Alertify.alert no es una función definida simplemente no lo esta.

Comment: ya he agregado el codigo html

Comment: Muestra también el error de consola por favor .. ya que así como está el código JS y el HTML.. debería funcionar...

Comment: el error de consola era porq en el html tenia una sentencia script vacia lo arregle pero sigue sin funcionar por si mismo el alertify